# Set default settings of a tool

Tags: inkscape

I created a circle with an ellipse tool and used node tool to slice pizza shape within it. Now each time I create a new circle I have this "puncture" (even when I open a new file).

I would like to know how to make Inkscape treat this entity as a whole circle again.

[image: Circle with "puncture"]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this: http://verysimpledesigns.com/vectors/inkscape-beginner-tips.html. Check your tool bars.

[image]

Comment: My experience with this sort of problem is that the program "remembers" the previously used setting. Once reset in Harley's manner, it should remain.